# Angular Firebase Auth Email/Password and Sign with Google

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I built Angular app with Firebase Auth. I added sign up with email/password and sing in with google. It is correct to join this two option? No I can create account with my google email and next use the same email in sign in with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

One of the main advantages of delegating the Auth to Firebase is that it will handle account merging for you. So the user can log in with the same email with different providers (email, google, facebook, etc..) but you will have just one user in your app.

If you would not use Firebase Auth, then you would need to manage this by yourself (which is not trivial).

Comment: But now after I sign up with email/password and after sign in with google a can't login with my email/password. Only sign in google working fine.

Comment: mh I had exactly what you mean using FirebaseUI, probably the Google one is considered more secure so it has priority over email/password login. I never considered it as a problem, since if a user uses the social login probably will not use the one with password anymore.